# Google reCAPTCHA: how to get only letters as a challenge

Tags: java, aem, recaptcha

I am using google reCAPTCHA version 2 in my project. It is working fine. But when I am checking the check box it is showing some set of images always as challenge. But I want to show only alphabets instead of images. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, currently there is no such configuration available to restrict the different types of image challenges that would be presented to the end user. The only setting available is to choose whether audio / image CAPTCHA needs to be served.

The entire list of available configurations [can be found here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#config) and you would notice that most of them are cosmetic settings.

There are [many discussions](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/recaptcha/u5xvWFSek00/ZCWKDWgs4NwJ) in google groups similar to your requirements, but I don't think there is any solution available yet.